# Axios EPERM: operation not permitted, read

Tags: reactjs, http, npm, axios

Axios was running fine but today i try to run my react app and get the error

./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/cookies.js
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read

i have tried uninstalling and installing it again but it still persists

any help would be highly valued